# Combine x rows based on key in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to learning pandas and ran across this problem today:

I'm building a simple df that collects health statistics, and each row represents one day of data per user. I want to see each individual user's weight loss in the data frame.

Here is a sample of my dataframe:

```
_id     _rev    body_mass   calories    date    name    sleep   steps   team    token   ua_id
xxxx    yyyy    60          3100    4/1/2017    user1   7        2800   t2      xxxx    123423
xxxx    yyyy    58          3300    4/1/2017    user2   6        2900   t1      xxxx    123439
xxxx    yyyy    45          3300    4/2/2017    user2   6        3300   t1      xxxx    123439
```

What I would like is a new df created with this information:

```
weight loss      name
0             user1
13            user2
```

Comment: But all the dates are equal. How de we know what the *firsst* measurement was?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to modify the 3rd row, 3rd row would be 4/2/2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by sorting the dataframe by user name and date, so that for each user the first line refers to the earliest measurement:

```
df_sorted = df.sort_values(['name','date'])
```

Then group the rows by user name and get the first (earliest) and last (most recent) measurement:

```
start = df_sorted.groupby('name').first()['body_mass']
end   = df_sorted.groupby('name').last()['body_mass']
```

Now, get the difference:

```
end - start
```

That's your result.

```
#name
#user1     0
#user2   -13
#Name: body_mass, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm figuring out how powerful pandas is day to day :).